# Prevent Clicking Again When Submitting Form in React

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a form in my React app and i wanted to disable or not be able to click the `Pay` button once i have submitted it. The problem is, that it is not submitting through API but through a `<form>`.

**Form**

```
<form ref={formEl} action="https://sample.aspx" method="POST">
  <input name="order" id="order" value={base64String} readOnly type="hidden" />
</form>
```

**Button**

```
<Button onClick={() => onPay(order.id)}>Pay</Button>;
```

**Pay Function**

```
const onPay = (id) => {
  formEl.current && formEl.current.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement this functionality, you should use form event `onSubmit`. Use any HTTP client like fetch or axios to call API. You can use a state value to track submission status.

**Form**

```html
    <form ref={formEl} action="https://sample.aspx" method="POST" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input name="order" id="order" value={base64String} readOnly type="hidden" />
    </form>
```

**Button**

```js
    <Button onClick={() => onPay(order.id)}>Pay</Button>;
```

**State**

```js
const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
```

**Pay Function**

```js
const onPay = (id) => {
  if (submitting) return;
  formEl.current && formEl.current.submit();
};
```

**Submit Function**

```js
const onSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSubmitting(true);
  await fetch('https://sample.aspx');
  setSubmitting(false);
}
```

Comment: Pls provide example and more info

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use boolean value to disable and enable it within useState.

   ```
    const [_boolValue, setBoolValue] = useState(true);

    <Button onClick={() => {
    setBoolValue(!_boolValue)
    onPay(order.id)
    }}>Pay</Button>;
   ```
2. then it will work only `_boolValue == true`

   ```
    const onPay = (id) => {
      _boolValue && formEl.current && formEl.current.submit();
    };
   ```

Comment: Pls provide example and more info

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` to keep track of when the button is clicked:

`const [paid, setPaid] = useState(false)`

Then set the button's `enabled` state based on the above. You can toggle the boolean within your `onPay` function.